# insert @@identity in the middle of string during insert

Tags: sql

I'm not sure if this is possible, but basically I want to do something like this...

```
insert into [DNSList].[dbo].[myTable] ([myValue]) values ('hello ' + convert(varchar,@@identity) + 'world')
```

Storing a value in the DB to be retrieved later and need a unique value in a certain place of the string, so figured just let sql keep track of the unique id and store it on entry.

Thanks for the help!

btw, using sql server 2008

**EDIT**
what if I do it this way, is it reliable?

```
declare @id as varchar
set @id = CONVERT(varchar,@@identity + 1)
insert into [DNSList].[dbo].[myTable] ([myValue]) values ('hello ' + @id + ' world')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the most direct way to do the insert.

```
declare @id as varchar
set @id = CONVERT(varchar,@@identity + 1)
insert into [DNSList].[dbo].[myTable] ([myValue]) values ('hello ' + @id + ' world')
```

Comment: I don't think this is what you want... You can't reference `@@identity` before doing the insert... you'll just get whatever ID was generated prior to your insert, which may be `NULL`, or may not be unique to your `DNSList` table.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the identity column won't be determined until after your insert, so you can't add it as part of the insert... however, you could do something similar using a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.myTable
ADD MyValue AS 'hello ' + convert(varchar, ID) + 'world' PERSISTED
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the Computed Column Idea more, but if the Hello world part was variable you could always use output:

```
-- What I imagine the table would look like
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable (
myID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
myValue NVARCHAR(2000)
)

DECLARE @TmpMyIDasString NVARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @TmpMyIDasINT INT
DECLARE @TmpTable TABLE(tmpID) -- You can only output in a table :/

INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (myValue)
     VALUES ('AnyText') 
     OUTPUT INSERTED.myId INTO @TmpTable

     -- Put it back in variables you can actually use
     SELECT @TmpMyIDasString = LTRIM(tmpID), 
            @TmpMyIDasINT = tmpID 
       FROM @TmpTable

     -- Update!  
     UPDATE dbo.MyTable 
        SET myValue = myValue+@TmpMyIDasString 
      WHERE myID = @TmpMyIDasINT
```

It does make you do the extra update after insert though....